# How can I use ISO times like 18:00 in react-big calendar

Tags: time, format, react-big-calendar

Cannot add time in ISO format in react-big-calendar

I am using react-big-calendar for my React project. For the other components I have formatted times like this: 18:00. I realized big-calendar works with 2019-3-12, but when I try to add 18:00 it considers the event as a whole-day one.

```
 'title': 'Meeting',
    'start': new Date(2015-3-12-11-0-0-0),
    'end': new Date(2015, 3, 12, 12, 30, 0, 0)
OR
 'title': 'Meeting',
    'start': new Date(2015-3-12, 11-0-0-0),
    'end': new Date(2015, 3, 12, 12, 30, 0, 0)
OR
 'title': 'Meeting',
    'start': new Date(2015-3-12, 11:00),
    'end': new Date(2015, 3, 12, 12, 30, 0, 0)
```

I would like to make it show up in the agenda view with the proper time.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way:

```
 'title': 'Meeting',
    'start': new Date('2015-04-12T21:45'),
    'end': new Date('2015-04-12T21:45'),
    desc: 'Pre-meeting meeting, to prepare for the meeting'
```